# How to apply autoNameResolution for quarkus-cxf?

Tags: cxf, quarkus

With quarkus cxf I try to generate the classes from the wsdl file. I get the following error:

```
Parameter: header already exists for method ping but of type be.belgium.fsb.v1_00.SyncHeader instead of be.belgium.fsb.v1_00.SyncResponseHeader.  Use a JAXWS/JAXB binding customization to rename the parameter.
```

With a cxf dependency with spring boot you can try to solve this by adding
`<autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>` to the plugin. Quarkus does not work with a plugin. How could I add the autoNameResolution to quarkus cxf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, the question doesn't contain neither any information about CFX plugin nor a sample WSDL fragment I assume it relates to Quarkiverse CFX Extensions.

This extension allows to generate Java class by WDSL using `wsdl2java`.

`quarkus.cxf.codegen.wsdl2java.additional-params` configuration property allows to set parameters to `wsdl2java` like this:

```
quarkus.cxf.codegen.wsdl2java.additional-params=-autoNameResolution
```

To pass `-xjc-*` parameters (e.g. `-xjc-Xboolean`) the following dependency need to be added to project.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkiverse.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-cxf</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**NOTE**: This dependency version (2.0.1) supports Quarkus 3. Now (May, 2023) Quarkus 3 is a brand new major version of Quarkus. So please choose the right  dependency version which is fit for your Quarkus version.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I do have problems, because now it works fine with quarkus3 and quarkus-csf 2.0.2 but i have to use it for quarkus 2.10.2 and when I downgrade to quarkus-cxf 1.73 or 1.5.5 it stops working. I don't find any docs on quarkus 2 anymore. Do you know if the configuration is different?